# new to iterm2 confused about this symbol on the top left side of window

Tags: iterm2

does anyone know what's the option command 1 symbol on the iterm window is?

I thought it was for name of tab but that's `cmd`+`#`

[image: iterm window]

Comment: This would be better researched and maybe posted to one of the Apple related SEs.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://gist.github.com/squarism/ae3613daf5c01a98ba3a#tabs-and-windows) it is `Go to Window` shortcut.